Keep pattern position
In a group, I have a pattern and another object.
When I move the group, the position of the pattern apparently stays relative to the background (and not the other object).
However, I want the position of the pattern to remain relative to the other object.
See the image below: When I move the group downwards, the pattern's position changes relative to the other object, which I do not want.


How can I prevent that behavior?

When using selector tool, enable in control bar the rightest icon (when hovering it with cursor, it displays : Move pattern (in fill or stroke) along with the objects
You could also use dashed strokes : in fill and stroke panel (keyboard shortcut : ctrl + shift + f), tab stroke style, you can set the exact stroke width you want), then you can use dashes (choose any in dropdown menu) and tweak it :

set the offset, in terms of stroke width (*) : with a 0 you begin the stroke with a full dash (stroke begins at the first node : beware of path direction).
and the pattern : the first number refers to dash length (in terms of stroke width), then type a space and the second number refers to the length of the space between dashes (always in terms of stroke width)

Example :
With a stroke width of 1.6 mm and an offset of 3 and a pattern of 6 1, you get a stroke begining with a half dash, and a dash length of 6x1.6=9.6 mm separated by a 1.6 mm wide space. With an offset of 6, you begin with an empty space of 1.6 mm.
Hope this helps.
